# Why does preventDefault on checkbox click event returns true for the checked attribute?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I am just curious and need some explanation on the following situation.

Let's say i have an input element of type checkbox with an eventlistener attached to it, listening for the click event. I prevent the default behavior of the checkbox and log the checked state of the checkbox, which will always return true.

The visual representation of the checkbox is telling me that it is not checked. So i would assume that the checked state would return false. I am sure this must be something silly and i am definitively misunderstanding something here. The funny thing is, i am logging the event itself as well. Inside of the target property the checked property is set to false, just as i would have expected.

From my understanding, prevent default will cancel the event without stopping propagation, so what exactly is happening here?

It would be great if someone could enlighten me on this one. Here is the example.

```js
var checkbox = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0],
    output = document.getElementById('output');

checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  output.innerHTML = "Checkbox checked attribute is " + this.checked;
  console.log(this.checked, evt.target.checked);
  console.log(evt);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox" />
<label for="my-checkbox">Checkbox with preventDefault().</label>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems as if the event's default action is actually cancelled after the bubbling stops, because if you log the checkbox's checked attribute, and the phase of the event in a parent element, you'll notice that it's still true (and the phase is 3, which means bubbling). It remains `true` up to the window, and then, I assume, `preventDefault()` actually prevents the default action, setting it to false: http://jsfiddle.net/j52ggg7x

Comment: This also might be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/j52ggg7x/1, with a timeout of 0 (which pushes the timeout function to the 'end'), the checked value will be false and the eventPhase will be `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the examples Alfonso. So would that mean, that the default behavior is prevented at the outer most object of the bubbling phase, in this case the window object?

Comment: Right after it finishes bubbling (when the eventPhase is 0. The phase is still 3 and checked is still true when the event is "on" the window, from what I remember from that fiddle. I can't see the log right now since I'm on mobile, ha). I'm just assuming though, it'd be nice to know for sure

Comment: That is exactly how it is. During event phase 3 on the window it is still true, on eventPhase 0 it is false.

Comment: So that seems to be how it is designed then. Perhaps a bounty can be offered to whoever explores the engine's code and tells us exactly what's happening in there :-) Or perhaps it is explained in detail in the spec, I'll look for that.

Comment: Will do that, just have to wait 8 more hours before i can start a bouty. :-)

Comment: It appears a similar issue has been [reported as bug on jquery](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10494). It's unclear from this though if this is expected behaviour

Comment: @Liam Thanks Liam, even if it feels odd it probably is the expected behavior. The bug is pretty old, so since nothing has changed, that could be actually how it is designed. But if it is so, there must be a reason and i'd love to understand it. ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, the result of the `checked` value in a `click` handler is **implementation dependent**.

As I tested in several browsers, Chrome/Firefox/Safari/Opera will always return true in this case, but IE/Edge's behavior gets a bit weird if you keep clicking on that checkbox element.

And I found this paragraph in the spec, which might be a explanation of this inconsistency:

> **Note**: During the handling of a click event on an input element with a type attribute that has the value "radio" or "checkbox", some implementations may change the value of this property before the event is being dispatched in the document. If the default action of the event is canceled, the value of the property may be changed back to its original value. This means that the value of this property during the handling of click events is implementation dependent.

But when I removed the `preventDefault` statement, the results in IE/Edge are consistent with the other browsers, which confuses me.

So I don't think it is IE/Edge's intended behavior… Therefore I filed [a bug on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1834135/preventdefault-in-the-click-event-handler-of-input-type-checkbox-causes-this-checked-value-inconsistent).

---

After all, if we presume Chrome's behavior to be standard-compliant, then the following might be a suitable explanation:

According to the [HTML Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox)), an `input[type=checkbox]` element's checkedness is restored at the canceled activation process, which comes after the event handlers according to the [Activation](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#activation) section. So during the execution of event handlers, the element's checkedness hasn't been restored yet.

(The spec doesn't explicitly state that canceled activation steps must come after all the event handlers; but it's easy to infer because otherwise there's no way to determine the event's canceled state)

Answer (score 7):

According to w3schools "The preventDefault() method cancels the event if it is cancelable, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur." The click event is cancelable (you can check it like this     *console.log("cancelable? "+ evt.cancelable);*.
So from what I understand, the default behavior of click event for a checkbox object is to read the current state of a checkbox and alternate  between true and false, consequently changing its state to checked and unchecked. In shorter words the default behavior is toggling; therefore, preventDefault() cancels that behavior.

In relation to checkboxes **checked = true; unchecked = false**.If you try to debug and follow eventListener step by step you will  see that once you in it **the unchecked box becomes "checked" even after stepping on *evt.preventDefault()*** so when you call   *console.log(this.checked, evt.target.checked);* at that time for the compiler your box is "checked", **the checkbox goes back to "unchecked" state only when eventListener done execution.** From this I can conclude that in case with checkboxes ***preventDefault() is actually activated(executed) at very last after all calls within event listener is executed***.

[image: Image represent some steps described in paragraph above]

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it. *Alfonso* pointed out what your saying as well. It is actually do to the fact, that the `click` event must dispatch on the topmost event target [event-click](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-click), not the case with the `mousedown` event, which will be dispatch immediately, only the `click` event will restore the checked value to it's former state, when default is prevented [default-cancel](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow-default-cancel). Could you quote the specs, so i can except. Maybe point out Mouse Event Order as well. Thanks.

Comment: Your explanation is more related to the fact when event is activated(starts). if you press the mouse key but will not release it, in click event, function will not start execution.
Whereas what alfonoso suggested was about bubbling and capturing,  which is related to the event FLOW. HTML elements nest inside eaach other and when you click on on one element(checkbox) you are also clicking on its parent(body->html->document->window), meaning the clicking on checkbox may effect its parents and descendants. Alfonso suggested that preventDefault isn't activated until certain element is reached.

Comment: My personal opinion is that such behavior of checkbox may be related to the fact that preventDefault() is called on EVENT object not on clicked object(not on checkbox). However I don't have 100% certainty (it will need a deeper research) that is why I didn't include it in my answer.

Comment: This is what i was trying to say in my comment. It's not related to the checkbox but to the click event itself. Try the same thing with mousedown or mouseup. The only relation in when it comes to checkboxes is that only the click event will restore the checkbox checked state. But dispatching takes place after bubbling has finished going all the way up to the window object.

Comment: I don't think it is related to bubbling, I checked it by enabling/disabling bubbling from the code you'll get same issue. Moreover, in some cases preventDefault() may stop bubbling.   So my opinion is:
it doesn't matter if event is mouseup or mousedown, it even doesn't matter whether it is click or touch event, or any other cancelable event....The main thing is EVENT.preventDefault() is function which is called on event OBJECT. Event Object provides information(properties) about particular event and passed to event handler, the question is at what point event handler applies those properties.