# Checkbox checked property does not update element when changed from RxJS subscribe callback

Tags: javascript, checkbox, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I found a very peculiar behavior that I cannot explain. I'm using RxJS to update a set of checkboxes based on a BehaviorSubject's value. I don't want to  change the checked attribute in the event handler nor let the browser handle it, so I use `preventDefault` and call `next` to set the new value. Then, in my `subscribe` callback I attempt to set the input's `checked` attribute, but it seemingly has no effect.

Run the snippet below, and try changing any of the checkboxes. Notice that each time the element's name and supposed `checked` value is logged, which would seem to indicate that everything's in order, except the inputs themselves do not change states. I added additional styling to make checked items more visible.

```js
const { BehaviorSubject } = rxjs;
const { distinctUntilChanged } = rxjs.operators;
const $checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'));
const settings = {
  a: false,
  b: true,
  c: false,
  d: false,
  e: true,
  f: true,
}
const sources = {};
const observers = {};
$checkboxes.forEach(el => {
  const { name } = el;
  el.checked = settings[name];
  sources[name] = new BehaviorSubject(el.checked);
  observers[name] = sources[name].asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name } = e.target;
    sources[name].next(!settings[name]);
  });
  observers[name].subscribe(value => {
    settings[name] = value;
    el.checked = settings[name];
    console.log(name, el.name, el.checked, value);
  });
})

console.clear();
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
}

input:checked + span {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="a"> <span>Option A</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="b"> <span>Option B</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="c"> <span>Option C</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="d"> <span>Option D</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="e"> <span>Option E</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f"> <span>Option F</span></label>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, this is just an MCVE, my actual code is split between multiple files and classes. I was thinking that maybe it has something to do with the way the variables are passed around, but notice that `el.name` and `name` are identical in the logged values, meaning that `el` should be the same element as before.

Wrapping the assignment to `el.checked` in a `setTimeout` appears to solve the issue, but doing that is almost never the right solution. I'd like to know what's causing this behavior and how I could make this kind of setup work without hacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preventDefault()` will restore value after click event listener is excuted. Please see 
[Why does preventDefault on checkbox click event returns true for the checked attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426523/why-does-preventdefault-on-checkbox-click-event-returns-true-for-the-checked-att)

You can use setTimeout(()=>xxx,0) to defer the execution in the next event loop which will happen after `preventDefault` run.

```js
const {
  BehaviorSubject,
  Observable,
  defer
} = rxjs;
const {
  distinctUntilChanged,
  map,
  mergeMap
} = rxjs.operators;
const $checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'));
const settings = {
  a: false,
  b: true,
  c: false,
  d: false,
  e: true,
  f: true,
}
const sources = {};
const observers = {};
$checkboxes.forEach(el => {
  const {
    name
  } = el;
  el.checked = settings[name];
  sources[name] = new BehaviorSubject(el.checked);
  observers[name] = sources[name].asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const {
      name
    } = e.target;
    sources[name].next(!settings[name]);

    e.preventDefault();

  });
  console.log(Observable)
  observers[name].pipe(map(value => {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      settings[name] = value;
      el.checked = settings[name];
      console.log(name, el.name, el.checked, value);
    }, 0)
  })).subscribe()
})

console.clear();
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
}

input:checked+span {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="a"> <span>Option A</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="b"> <span>Option B</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="c"> <span>Option C</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="d"> <span>Option D</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="e"> <span>Option E</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="f"> <span>Option F</span></label>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.2.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to the explanation, I was not aware that preventDefault caused this, but now it does make sense. It looks like setTimeout *is* the simplest way to get around this after all.