# changing of checked property of checkbox in DOM not working with event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript

I understand that if you change some property in DOM it is reflected in UI and event.preventDefault() function prevents the default changes . Now in this script i changed DOM and stopped default action but it is not reflecting in interace ?

```js
let check = document.getElementById('check');
check.onclick = function(event) {
  event.target.checked = !event.target.checked;
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox
```

Comment: what exactly you want to happen?

Comment: i want checkbox to toggle but it is not happening , @connexo yes i am doing it myself but it is not working

Comment: @ArpitKarwasara remove the js .checkbox  have a default  toggle

Comment: @prasanth yes they have but i need to implement some more features which require me to control default behaviour , now when on console you do check.target.checked = !check.target.checked it works but not in this case

Answer (score 4):

In this specific example, of course, you could just not have the handler. But you've indicated in the comments that the situation is more complex than shown in the question.

You have to let the event finish being processed before you can change the checked state of the box and have that change stick, for instance with the old `setTimeout(..., 0)` trick:

```js
let check = document.getElementById('check');
check.addEventListener("click", function({target}) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    target.checked = !target.checked;
  }, 0);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox
```

(Just a microtask like `Promise.resolve().then(...)` doesn't work, at least on Chrome, apparently you have to go back to the main event loop.)

That example also uses `addEventListener` rather than `onclick` and ES2015+ destructuring (the `{target}` in the function parameter list), since you're using `let` and so appear to be using ES2015+.

But it works using `onclick`, too:

```js
let check = document.getElementById('check');
check.onclick = function({target}) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    target.checked = !target.checked;
  }, 0);
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox" /> Checkbox
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowser but what i understand is that since javascript is executing the browser is either done with handling the event or it will handle it later , what is still being processed ?

Comment: @ArpitKarwasara This might shed some light: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426523/why-does-preventdefault-on-checkbox-click-event-returns-true-for-the-checked-att?rq=1

Comment: @ArpitKarwasara - The handling of events is a back-and-forth between the DOM (in the browser) and your JavaScript code. Your handler runs while the DOM is dispatching the event to the checkbox, but the event also bubbles to the ancestor elements of the checkbox. So there's more processing to do even after your event handler finishes. (I should say that I don't quite understand *why* `preventDefault` and changing `checked` yourself doesn't work in this case. It'll be somewhere [in here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#events), but... :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the help guys , 
After digging i came to this conclusion that:

1) Initially the browser toggles the checked value and calls the event listener

2) Now it again encounters a toggle statement and it toggles the value again , now the value is back to original

3) Now preventDefault() is called which is executed after the bubble of eventlisteners (i think) and it sees that the new value of checked is same as the initial value(which i think it keeps track of ) and does nothing (if it was changed it would toggle again).

If you replace the line -  event.target.checked = !event.target.checked; 
you can see preventDefault() toggling but in this case it does not toggle .