# Why does the e.preventDefault function in javascript not work for the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When writing the code I encountered a problem that I can not solve myself. Well, it did not work for me `if (checkbox.checked == false)`, but `if (checkbox.checked == true)` works, even though the checkbox is not selected. 
I checked it on Opera and Edge. Is this a common problem? Is there any way to get around this?

JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/mk5j6170/)

Comment: `document.querySelecotr` Spelling matters in programming. Always check your browser console for errors before asking why things aren't working. Fix that, and your code works. You should also always post all the relevant code **in the question itself**, in a [MCVE]

Comment: The correct reaction to SO telling you you can't post jsFiddle links without *also* posting the relevant code **in** the question wasn't to mark up the link as code. If you want people on the site to help you, please follow the rules of the site. The full content of your question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: You can make your MCVE **runnable, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a simple error when rewriting the code. It still does not solve my problem, because the "checkboc.checked" function does not work.

Comment: I am new here and I do not understand everything yet, and you are clinging to mistakes instead of helping me. Thank you for correcting me, next time I will do it better. Since everyone knows how to write questions but nobody knows programming, I do not want your help.

Comment: We all know programming. The problem is that it is very hard to help you when not asking a clear question. Put yourself in my position - I know nothing about your problem and want to help you solve it. My help will only be as good as the description of the problem that you give me. In this case right here you give a very poor description, which makes it very hard for me to help. We need an actual problem description with as much information as you can give. For example you say `"checkboc.checked" function does not work` - I must ask myself what does "not work" mean? What is the exact problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have an spelling-error in your code: `querySelecotr` should be `querySelector`.
You can also use `getElementById` to get an element by its id-property.

Both versions work in the browsers i tested *(Firefox, Chrome, Safari)*.

If you use `preventDefault()`, the checked-state will be **restored after** the event-handler is completed. So any change inside that event-handler will be reverted. A workaround would be to toggle the state with inside an `setTimeout`-call *(see checkbox3-example below)*.

```js
let idCheckbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
idCheckbox.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});


let idCheckbox2 = document.querySelector("#checkbox2");
idCheckbox2.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

let idCheckbox3 = document.querySelector("#checkbox3");
idCheckbox3.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (idCheckbox3.checked == false) {
      idCheckbox3.checked = true;
    } else {
      idCheckbox3.checked = false;
    }
  }, 50);
});
```

```html
<input id="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="sub-label" for="checkbox">Accept checkbox 1</label>
<br>
<input id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="sub-label" for="checkbox2">Accept checkbox 2</label>
<br>
<input id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" type="checkbox"/>
<label class="sub-label" for="checkbox3">Accept checkbox 3</label>
<br>
```

Comment: Try: `var idCheckbox = document.querySelector("#checkbox");

idCheckbox.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(idCheckbox.checked == false){
     idCheckbox.checked = true;
    }else{
     idCheckbox.checked = false;
    }
    
}, false);`

Comment: I included that version in my answer. And both versions work on all the recent browsers i use (Firefox, Chrome, Safari).

Comment: The opera does not work on EDGE if I double click

Comment: You had an spelling error in your code: `querySelecotr`

Comment: "e.preventDefault ()" in jsfiddle did not work because I made a mistake but still do not work in the opera and EDGE (checkbox.checked == true / false), (checkbox.checked = true / false)

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that part of your question *(checkbox3)*. The checked-property behaves a bit strange if you read it inside an (prevented) click-event of a checkbox-element.

Comment: Thank you for being the only one who is trying to help me. The checked-property behaves a little strangely always.

Comment: I did also an mistake in the third example. Let me check again.

Comment: All three checkboxes do not work in the Opera or EDGE.

Comment: I managed to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426523/why-does-preventdefault-on-checkbox-click-event-returns-true-for-the-checked-att) thread. It shows that the "checked" function of "checkbox" simply does not work. (At least I understood it that way).

Comment: Hey Krzystof, i did some reading on the event-handling of checkboxes. And found a working solution. See the checkbox3-example again and also the changed informations in my answere above. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: The checked-property (its not a function) does work, but all the changes to it if made inside the event-hanlder, will be reverted at the end of the event-handler if preventDefault is used.

Comment: It works! I do not quite understand what "setTimeout" gives you. Thank you very much. I will be grateful if you change me into the source of this solution.

Comment: `setTimeout` will execute a function after an specified delay (in this case 50ms). So it will run after the event-handler is finished and already restored the checked-property. So when we change the checked-property inside the setTimeout it will not be overwritten.