# Why does preventDefault on parent element disable programmatically checking child checkbox on click?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, preventdefault

A `div` element's click event has `e.preventDefault()` at the beginning. That makes manually clicking the checkbox `input` or it's associated `label` inside no longer works.

With the help of some more JavaScript code, manually clicking the `label` generates expected results because the checkbox is now programmatically checked/unchecked.

However, manually clicking the checkbox `input` still does not work despite the fact that similar JavaScript code for programmatically checking/unchecking has been implemented. Why?

```js
document.querySelector('div').onclick = function (e)
{
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'LABEL')
      {
          e.target.previousElementSibling.checked = !e.target.previousElementSibling.checked;
      }
      else if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT')
      {
          e.target.checked = !e.target.checked;
      }
}
```

```html
<div>
      <input  id="check" type="checkbox">
      <label for="check">Label Text</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does preventDefault on checkbox click event returns true for the checked attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426523/why-does-preventdefault-on-checkbox-click-event-returns-true-for-the-checked-att)

Comment: @pilchard It does not. My question is why programmatically checking the checkbox does not work.

Comment: If you read through the answers you will find ample discussion of just that question, also if you log the `checked` property of the checkbox in your function you will see that it toggles on and then off again indicating that your programmatic change is registered and then overridden by the prevent default (also discussed in the duplicate answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking the `label` sets the `checked` property as expected because there is no `default` action related to the label to be canceled. Clicking the `input` sets the property as expected, but due to the default action (toggling the checked property) being prevented it reverts to its previous state.

see: [Why does preventDefault on checkbox click event returns true for the checked attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426523/why-does-preventdefault-on-checkbox-click-event-returns-true-for-the-checked-att) for more in depth discussion.

```js
document.querySelector('div').onclick = function (e)
{
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'LABEL')
      {
          e.target.previousElementSibling.checked = !e.target.previousElementSibling.checked;
      }
      else if (e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() == 'INPUT')
      {
      console.clear();
      console.log(e.target.checked);
          e.target.checked = !e.target.checked;
      console.log(e.target.checked);
}
}
```

```html
<div>
      <input  id="check" type="checkbox">
      <label for="check">Label Text</label>
</div>
```

**Edit**

In response to your comment I think the cleanest solution would be to explicitly apply listeners to those elements that you want to control outside of the provided API methods calling `stopPropagation()` on them to avoid triggering the parent listeners.

You can then handle whatever logic you need without having to work around artifacts of the outside methods. If you need the parent to listener to run as well you can programmatically activate it after your control logic is finished.

```js
// original API listener
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // add container specific code
  console.log('clicked div');
 
});

// your isolated listener
document.querySelector('.checkbox-container').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation(); // stop the event from propagating to the parent listener
  
  // add checkbox specific code 
  console.clear();
  console.log('clicked checkbox container');
  
  // even programmatically 'clicking' parent if you need to
  e.currentTarget.parentElement.click();
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.checkbox-container {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkbox-container">
    <input id="check" type="checkbox">
    <label for="check" >Label Text</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to make programmatically checking work on clicking the checkbox?

Comment: I tried `setTimeout` and it worked. But I would like to know if there is another way.

Comment: This feels a little like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The simplest solution is to not handle input state in the listener at all and let the built-in functionality handle itself, what is it you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The listener is added to the parent element by a plugin called PhotoSwipe (https://photoswipe.com/) via its `onThumbnailsClick` function. The `e.preventDefault()` is at the beginning of that function. What I'm trying to accomplish is making my checkboxes work (they are inside the parent element).

Comment: edited with recommendation for working with the external api

Comment: Thank you! The `e.stopPropagation()` solution is smart :)

Answer (score 2):

Prevent default propagates often propagates down to the child.  There is a way to stop that from happening by using using event.stopPropagation.  Read here to learn more about other useful methods that might help your cause.

https://chunkybyte.medium.com/the-one-with-event-propagation-and-e-preventdefault-part-1-6d84f3c4220