# Checkbox doesn't checked using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, frontend, ejs

I'm working on my web application using NodeJS, EJS and JQuery. Using JQuery I'am able to detect click event on checkbox but checkbox doesn't appeare checked.

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" class="myClass">
```

JQuery

```
function checkboxDefault(){

  $("#myCHeck1").attr("checked", false);
  $("#myCHeck2").attr("checked", true);
}

$(function() {

  $(document).on('click', ".myClass", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var event = $(this).attr("id");

    if(event == "myCheck1")
        $("#myCheck1").attr("checked", true);
    else
        $("#myCheck2").attr("checked", false);

    });


});
```

I tried using $("#myCheck*").prop, instead .attr() but it doesn't work. Click event and right checkbox ID are rightly detected. Can you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
prop('checked', true) // to check the box
prop('checked', false) // to uncheck the box
```

Also #myCHeck1 isn't it a typo?
H is big

Comment: H is big because I misspelled, sorry.  I tried to use prop method and it doesn't work .Thanks

Comment: Well if has to. That mean that is not the problem. Do you have 1 checkbox or 2? 
Why do you use #myCheck1? if id is myCheck2 here <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" class="myClass"> ?

Comment: I wrote a simple code to emulate my problem. The point is that: when I click myCheck1, the line ```$("#myCheck1").attr("checked", true);``` does not check the box. I'm sure that event is right and all code in true statement is running. Only this line doesn't work. Inspecting my HTML code using browser I see ```checked="checked" ``` so, maybe its a rendering problem?

Comment: The problem comes from your `e.preventDefault();` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426523/why-does-preventdefault-on-checkbox-click-event-returns-true-for-the-checked-att) are some explanations

Comment: Thanks for the help. Removing ```6e.preventDefault()``` its working!